# terraform to append consul_key values in json

Tags: terraform, consul

I have a project on which I have to use terraform and in the end of the terraform, I need to append consul key's values places on a /path. I have the following:

```
resource "consul_keys" "write" {
  datacenter = "dc1"
  token = "xxxx-x-x---xxxxxx--xx-x-x-x"
  key {
    path = "path/to/name"
    value = jsonencode([
      {
        cluster_name = "test", "region" : "us-east1" 
      },
    {
            cluster_name = "test2", "region" : "us-central1" 
        }
    ])
  }
}
```

But if I run the terraform again with new values, it deletes all previous values and update new values.

Any way I can keep appending the values keeping previous values as it is?

Answer (score 0):

[The `consul_keys` resource type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/consul/latest/docs/resources/keys) in [the `hashicorp/consul` provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/consul/latest) only supports situations where it is responsible for managing the entirety of the value of each of the given keys. This is because [the underlying Consul API](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/kv#create-update-key) itself treats each key as a single atomic unit, and doesn't support partial updates of the sort you want to achieve here.

If you are able to change the design of the system that is *consuming* these values, a different way to get a comparable result would be to set aside a particular key *prefix* as a collection of values that the consumer will merge together after reading them. [Consul's Read Key API](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/kv#read-key) includes a mode `recurse=true` which allows you to provide a prefix to read all of the entries with a given prefix in a single request.

By designing your key structure this way, you can use a separate keys for the data that Terraform will provide and the data provided by each other system that will generate data under this shared prefix. These different systems can therefore each maintain their own designated sub-key and not need to take any special extra steps to preserve existing data already stored at that location.

If you are using `consul-template` then [`consul-template`'s `ls` function](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/blob/master/docs/templating-language.md#ls) wraps the multi-key lookup I described above.

If you are reading the data from Consul in some other Terraform configuration, [the `consul_key_prefix` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/consul/latest/docs/data-sources/key_prefix) similarly implements the operation of fetching all key/value pairs under a given prefix.